# How to add perfectly the facebook open graph meta tags to blogger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, blogger

Iam trying to add this code This is correct way to add or any thing wrong in this code. I presently run my website in blogger.

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='logo-link' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != ""'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
<meta content='app_id' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='fb_admins' property='fb:admins'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following line should be change. FROM

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

TO

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

In your code, Blogger will use it's default thumbnail as 72px X 72px size. I have changed it to the original size path.

You can also include author markup into this code by adding the following line, below to `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>` in your Blogger source code.

```
<meta expr:content='data:post.author' name='author'/>
```